# Rearrange Sibling Nodes in id_tree Rust

Tags: rust, tree

I'd like to rearrange siblings in an [id_tree](https://docs.rs/id_tree/1.7.0/id_tree/index.html). I see that id_tree includes methods for making a node the first or last sibling in a group of children, `make_first_sibling()` and `make_last_sibling()` respectively, but id_tree's `move_node()` seems to only be useful for moving a node to the root or to a new parent, not rearranging siblings indices.

If you wanted to move a node to some arbitrary index within the sibling array, how might you do that?

[id_tree `Tree` docs](https://docs.rs/id_tree/1.7.0/id_tree/struct.Tree.html)

```rust
use id_tree::*;

struct MyTree{
    pub tree: Tree<i32>
}

impl MyTree{
    pub fn insert_node(&mut self, node: &NodeId, pos: u32){
        //inserts node as some pos within the array of its parents children (siblings) 
        //        Z
        //     / / \ \
        //    A  B  C  D
        //insert_node(A, 2)
        //        Z
        //     / / \ \
        //    B  C  A  D
        
    }
}

fn main() {
    use id_tree::InsertBehavior::*;

        MyTree{
            tree: Tree<i32> = TreeBuilder::new()
            .with_node_capacity(5)
            .build();
        }

    let root_id: NodeId = my_tree.tree.insert(Node::new(0), AsRoot).unwrap();
    let child_id: NodeId = my_tree.tree.insert(Node::new(1), UnderNode(&root_id)).unwrap();
    my_tree.tree.insert(Node::new(2), UnderNode(&root_id)).unwrap();
    my_tree.tree.tree.insert(Node::new(3), UnderNode(&root_id)).unwrap();
    my_tree.tree.insert(Node::new(4), UnderNode(&root_id)).unwrap();

}
```

Perhaps the source code for the `make_first_sibling()` function would be helpful?

```rust
pub fn make_first_sibling(&mut self, node_id: &NodeId) -> Result<bool, NodeIdError> {
    let (is_valid, error) = self.is_valid_node_id(node_id);
    if !is_valid {
        return Err(error.expect(
            "Tree::make_first_sibling: Missing an error value but found an invalid NodeId.",
        ));
    }

    let mut moved = false;
    if let Some(parent_id) = self.get(node_id)?.parent().cloned() {
        let parent = self
            .get_mut(&parent_id)
            .expect("Tree::make_first_sibling: invalid parent id");
        let mut position = parent.children.iter().position(|id| id == node_id).unwrap();
        moved = position > 0;
        while position > 0 {
            parent.children.swap(position - 1, position);
            position -= 1;
        }
    }
    Ok(moved)
}
```

Comment: I read API of the library and it seems to be possible but ineffective. I think, you should just ask a maintainers of library to add this or ever make PR.

Comment: At this moment you can do such thing: add to payload some u8 field, then make all items prior moved with value 0, needed item 1, and others 2. Then you can sort children: https://docs.rs/id_tree/1.7.0/id_tree/struct.Tree.html#method.sort_children_by_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`swap_nodes`](https://docs.rs/id_tree/1.7.0/id_tree/struct.Tree.html#method.swap_nodes) to shuffle a node from its current position to the desired position.

For example:

```rust
use id_tree::*;

trait TreeExt {
    fn move_node_to_pos(&mut self, node: &NodeId, pos: usize) -> Result<(), NodeIdError>;
}
 
impl TreeExt for Tree<i32> {

    /// Move the indicated child so that it has position `pos` under its parent
    ///        Z
    ///     / / \ \
    ///    A  B  C  D
    ///
    /// move_node_to_pos(A, 2)
    ///        Z
    ///     / / \ \
    ///    B  C  A  D
    fn move_node_to_pos(&mut self, node: &NodeId, pos: usize) -> Result<(), NodeIdError> {

        let parent = self.get(node)?.parent()
            .ok_or(NodeIdError::NodeIdNoLongerValid)?
            .clone();

        let num_children = self.children_ids(&parent)?.count();
        if pos >= num_children {
            return Err(NodeIdError::NodeIdNoLongerValid);
        }
        
        // First determine the current index that the node has
        // unwrap should not be reachable, since we are searching under node's
        // own parent, barring bugs in id_tree
        let mut current_pos = self.children_ids(&parent)?
            .enumerate()
            .find_map(|(i, n) | if n==node { Some(i) } else { None })
            .unwrap();
        
        while current_pos != pos {
            let pos_to_swap = if current_pos < pos {
                current_pos+1
            } else if current_pos > pos {
                current_pos-1
            } else {
                break;
            };
            let node_to_swap = self.children_ids(&parent)?.nth(pos_to_swap).unwrap().clone();
            self.swap_nodes(node, &node_to_swap, SwapBehavior::TakeChildren)?;
            current_pos = pos_to_swap;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Here I have defined an extension trait to add a method `move_node_to_pos` to the `Tree`.

To avoid lifetime issues, we clone both the parent `&NodeId` and the `&NodeId` of the node I swap with inside the loop. Otherwise, the immutable borrows you have taken on the tree to obtain the nodes prevents you from calling `swap_node`.

The error handling is not really correct in this sample implementation - you would not really want to return `NodeIdError` as an error type because there are some other error conditions that occur, such as requesting a position larger than the current number of nodes under the parent, or trying to do this for a node that has no parent.

Example usage:

```rust
fn main() {
    use id_tree::InsertBehavior::*;

    let mut my_tree = TreeBuilder::<i32>::new()
            .with_node_capacity(5)
            .build();

    let root_id: NodeId = my_tree.insert(Node::new(0), AsRoot).unwrap();
    let c1: NodeId = my_tree.insert(Node::new(1), UnderNode(&root_id)).unwrap();
    let _c2 = my_tree.insert(Node::new(2), UnderNode(&root_id)).unwrap();
    let _c3 = my_tree.insert(Node::new(3), UnderNode(&root_id)).unwrap();
    let _c4 = my_tree.insert(Node::new(4), UnderNode(&root_id)).unwrap();

    for (i,n) in my_tree.children(&root_id).unwrap().enumerate() {
        println!("i={} n={:?}", i, n.data());
    }
    
    my_tree.move_node_to_pos(&c1, 3).unwrap();

    for (i,n) in my_tree.children(&root_id).unwrap().enumerate() {
        println!("i={} n={:?}", i, n.data());
    }

}
```